# BeautifulSoup - getting rid of paragraph whitespace/line breaks

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
similarlist = res.find_all_next("div", class_="result-wrapper")
for item in similarlist:
    print(item)
```

This returns:

```
<div class="result-wrapper">
<div class="row-fluid result-row">
<div class="span6 result-left">
<p>
<a class="tooltipLink warn-cs" data-original-title="Listen" href="..." rel="tooltip"><i class="..."></i></a>
<a class="muted-link" href="/dictionary/german-english/aa-machen">Aa <b>machen</b></a>
</p>
</div>   
<div class="span6 result-right row-fluid">
<span class="span9">
<a class="muted-link" href="/dictionary/english-german/do-a-poo">to do a poo</a>, <a class="muted-link" href="/dictionary/english-german/pooh">to pooh</a>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

When I choose to print `item.get_text()` instead, I get

```
abgeneigt machen
to disincline




abhängig machen
2137

to predicate




Absenker machen
to layer
```

So basically a lot of new lines between the list items that I don't need. Is this because of the `<p>` tags? How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, between tags the HTML contains whitespace (including newlines) too.

You can easily collapse all multi-line whitespace with a regular expression:

```
import re

re.sub(r'\n\s*\n', r'\n\n', item.get_text().strip(), flags=re.M)
```

This removes any whitespace (newlines, spaces, tabs, etc.) between two newlines.

Answer (score -3):

You can the the strip() function in python

item.get_text().strip()

Comment: This only removes whitespace from the start and end, not the middle.